# Steam API get groups as json

Tags: php, json, steam, steam-web-api

I was looking around, but I could not find any way to fetch the groups that the user is in.  The only thing I can retrieve right now is the primary clan id of the user.  I would like to be able to see all the groups the user is in for my app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using the following feed?

```
http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetUserGroupList/v0001/?key=your_api_key&steamid=[Steam64 id of user]
```